# New country visited after applying for a B1 visa to the US. How can I update my application?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I submitted my DS 160 for a B1 visa and was scheduled an appointment for 15 days later. In the meanwhile I traveled to a different country (Thailand) and thus my list of countries visited is not up to date. Will this be a problem?

My application is with the US consulate at Dubai.

Comment: Just be honest with the Immigration Officer and tell them that you visited more countries since then.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've traveled to Syria/Iraq/Iran, I wouldn't bother mentioning it. Legally speaking you're only responsible for telling the truth *at the time the form was filled*.

If you really want to be on the safe side, mention that you've traveled to a new country in that period and ask them to amend your application.